# Issues Installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I would like to completely install Ubuntu on to my computer with no dual boot. I have not been able to find any solutions to my problem. When I am booting from my live usb drive there are no options for installing Ubuntu. Same with a live cd, I have tried out all my options. I can not wipe the whole disk and install Ubuntu. I can not install Ubuntu on one of the partitions that I have created. I have disabled fast start-up . I have disabled secure start-up. I have tried to use some of the tools on the Ubuntu side to assist an installation. All to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: What stops you from doing all those things you can not do? Please use detailed language in place of general statements.

Comment: When you boot to the live media there are two options, one of them is to **Install Ubuntu** and the other option is to **Try Ubuntu**.  It's hard to imagine that you are misseeing the **Install** option.  If you look again and see it clock on it and tell us exactly what you are doing and where you get stuck if you do.  If you don't see those two options, please tell us what you see when you boot to the Live USB media.  Look at these steps [Install Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#2) and tell us where you get stuck.

Comment: Go to BIOS and enable Legacy Support, seems that the program that you used for putting the iso file in the usb doesnt work for EFI so enabling Legacy Mode will now prompt you options also use F9-F12 keys for manual booting the USB

Comment: Changing to legacy did not seem to help. I can boot up from the usb  drive but  this option https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#4 never appears. This is the issue I am having. Thanks for the help

Comment: You might consider clarifying your question, to indicate that you are having problems booting to the Live USB or DVD.  The close votes you see are results of this not being clear.  Can you describe what you see when you attempt to boot to the USB or DVD?  You have described what you don't see.  But the steps to take would be clearer if we knew what you actually see.  Are there any words at all on the screen?  Is it just a black screen?  Is it a purple screen?  When responding, if you use @[myuserid], I'll receive a notice to check this thread.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ya, thanks for the help guys but I figured it out. I entered the command `gparted` during a live session and that fixed all the issues I was having. When I entered that command the application started asking me if it should "fix" many things and that did the trick. I was able to wipe the disk and install ubuntu like I wanted. This was probably just a newbie mistake. It was the first time that I have installed ubuntu.

Comment: Your answer doesn't match your question or any of the details in your comments.  Wipe disk is one of the install options of the live USB.  You don't need gparted to get to the install options.  You just need to boot to the live USB and click Install to get to the install options.